# What are the attributes of pativrata stree?

Tags: marriage, women

What are the attributes of patrivrata stree? How can we identify a pativrata stree?

Answer (score 1):

As per vAlmiki rAmAyaNa ayodhyakhanda [ch. 117](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga117/ayodhya_117_frame.htm) & [ch. 118](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga118/ayodhya_118_frame.htm) :

> *"Highly fortunate worlds await those women, await those women, to whom their husband is dear no matter whether he lives in a city or in
> a forest; whether he is sinful or virtuous." २-११७-२२*
>
> *"O, venerable woman! Even if my husband be without fortune, he should unhesitatingly be obeyed by me." २-११८-३*
>
> *"To women of noble nature, the husband is the highest deity no mater whether he is ill-behaved or licentious or devoid of riches."
> २-११७-२३*
>
> *"Those evil women, whose hearts follow their passions and conduct themselves dominating their husband, having no understanding of virtue
> and vice, do not follow him in the aforesaid manner." २-११७-२५*

As per [mahAbhArata vanaparva CCXXXI](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03231.htm)

> - But the wife should never do the least injury to her lord.
> - Keeping aside vanity, and controlling desire and wrath, I always serve with devotion the sons of Pandu with their wives.
> - Restraining jealousy, with deep devotion of heart, without a sense of    degradation at the services I perform, I wait upon my husbands.
> - Ever fearing to utter what is evil or false, or to look or sit or    walk with impropriety, or cast glances indicative of the feelings of the heart, do I serve the sons of Pritha--those mighty warriors blazing like the sun or fire, and handsome as the moon, those endued with fierce energy and prowess, and capable of slaying their foes by a glance of the eye.
> - I never bathe or eat or sleep till he that is my husband hath bathed    or eaten or slept,--till, in fact, our attendants have bathed, eaten,    or slept.
> - Whether returning from the field, the forest, or the town, hastily    rising up I always salute my husband with water and a seat.
> - I always keep the house and all household articles and the food that    is to be taken well-ordered and clean.
> - Carefully do I keep the rice, and serve the food at the proper time.
> - I never indulge in angry and fretful speech, and never imitate women    that are wicked.
> - I never laugh except at a jest, and never stay for any length of time    at the house-gate.
> - I never stay long in places for answering calls of nature, nor in    pleasure-gardens attached to the house.
> - I always refrain from laughing loudly and indulging in high passion,    and from everything that may give offence.
> - When my husband leaveth home for the sake of any relative, then renouncing flowers and fragrant paste of every kind, I begin to undergo penances.
> - Whatever my husband drinketh not, whatever my husband eateth not, whatever my husband enjoyeth not, I ever renounce.
> - O beautiful lady, decked in ornaments and ever controlled by the    instruction imparted to me, I always devotedly seek the good of my lord.
> - I never, in sleeping or eating or adorning any person, act against    the wishes of my lord, and always guided by my husbands, I never speak ill of my mother-in-law.
> - Never do I show any preference for myself over her in matters of food    and attire, and never do I reprove in words that princess
>   equal unto    the Earth herself in forgiveness.
> - And those bulls among the Bharatas, throwing upon me the burden of    looking after all those that were to be fed by them, would, O thou of handsome face, pay their court to me. And this load, so heavy and incapable of being borne by persons of evil heart, I used to bear day and night, sacrificing my ease, and all the while affectionately devoted to them.
> - And while my husbands were engaged in the pursuit of virtue, I only    supervised their treasury inexhaustible like the ever-filled receptacle of Varuna.

[padmapurANa bhumIkhanDa ch. 47](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc364254.html)

> *Both the parents get the (fruit of the) sin which a daughter, living in her father’s house, commits. Therefore an able (i.e. a grown up) daughter is not kept in his house (by the father). She should get nourishment in the house of him to
> whom she is given. She, living there, should devoutly win over her
> virtuous husband. The family becomes famous; the father lives happily.*

[shivapurANa rudrasamhita pArvatIkhanda ch. 54](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226118.html)

> *72. O gentle lady, the chaste ladies can be divided into four classes. Even when they are remembered they dispel sins. The divisions
> comprise of the superior etc.*
>
> *73. They are superior, middling, inferior and very inferior. I shall explain their characteristics. Listen with attention.*
>
> *74. O gentle lady, she whose mind is not aware of any one else and who is conscious of her husband even in her dreams is the noblest of
> all.*
>
> *75. O daughter of the mountain, she who sees another man as her father, brother or son with a clean conscience is the middling among
> chaste ladies.*
>
> *76. O Pārvatī, she who ponders over her duty mentally and desists from going astray is inferior among the chaste. Of course she is pure
> in conduct.*
>
> *77. She who remains chaste for fear of her husband or the family is very inferior among the chaste ladies, so say the ancient poets.*
>
> *78. O Pārvatī, these four types of chaste ladies dispel sins. They sanctify all the worlds. They are delighted here and hereafter.*