# Scriptural References on Code of Conduct in Marriage for wife

Tags: puranas, marriage, smriti, wife

Manusmriti, I guess, states as :

> A woman is never supposed to live independently. During young age, she is to live under the protection of her father, after being married, under her husband, and after being widowed, in aegis of her sons.

What are other dos and don'ts injuncted by the scriptures for wife? It could be anything from dressing modestly to putting boundaries to avoid infidelity or disrespect or etc. Please include the references too.

Thanks.

Comment: check this - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/54248/21696